# CSS: Cut Corner of the two div and keep in sync along with background variable heigh

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create the below layout.
[image]

This what I have tried so far to make it working but stuck with the Bottom text width and Image alignment.

```css
.page {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #DEDEDE;
}

.landscape {
    height: 8.2in;
    font-size: 10px;
    position: relative;
    page-break-after: always;
    /* page-break-inside: avoid; */
    font-family: Verdana;
}


.bp-coverpage-3 {   

    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}


.bp-coverpage-3  .bp-coverpage-header {
        width: 100%;
        height: 3.2in;
    }

.bp-coverpage-3 .LogoImageSize {
    max-height: 1.6in;
    max-width: 3.1in;
}

.bp-coverpage-3 .bp-coverpage-header > .header-section-top {
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 5%;
}

.bp-coverpage-3 .bp-coverpage-header .client-tag-line {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 25px;
}

.bp-coverpage-3 .bp-coverpage-header .header-section-bottom {
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 10%;
}

.bp-coverpage-3 .bp-coverpage-content {
    width: 100%;
    border:1px solid #999;
    font-family: Manrope SemiBold !important;
    background: url(https://as2.ftcdn.net/v2/jpg/04/38/64/95/1000_F_438649569_DsSHTkasH6GqqQXwu7FbRG0OMHstAc2D.jpg) no-repeat bottom -120px right -170px ;
    background-size: 80%;
}

.bp-coverpage-3  .content-section-top {
  background:transparent;
}

.bp-coverpage-3  .content-section-bottom {
  background-color:transparent;
}
.bp-coverpage-3 .bp-coverpage-content  .report-name-container {
        padding: 0px 0px 0px 40px;
        background: #61626B;
        width:35%;
        position:relative;
        z-index:1;
    }
.bp-coverpage-3 .bp-coverpage-content  .report-name-container:after {
  content:'';
  border-bottom: 140px solid #61626B;
  border-left: 120px solid transparent;
  border-right: 120px solid transparent;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  right:-80px;
  z-index:-1;
}
.bp-coverpage-3 .bp-coverpage-content  .report-name-container:before {
  content:'';
  border-top: 90px solid #61626B;
  border-left: 120px solid transparent;
  border-right: 120px solid transparent;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  right:-80px;
        z-index:-1;
}
.bp-coverpage-3 .report-name-container > .report-name {
    font-size: 32px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    font-family: 'Manrope SemiBold';    
    word-break: break-word;
    width:2.8in;
    height:1.5in;    
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

.bp-coverpage-3 .bp-coverpage-content  .content-section-bottom .bottom-shape {
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 40px;
    background: #61626B;
    width:calc(40% + 25px);
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
    background:#E7E7E7;
}

.bp-coverpage-3 .bp-coverpage-content  .content-section-bottom .bottom-shape:after {
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    border-left: 80px solid #E7E7E7;
    border-top: 81px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 0px solid transparent;
    top:0;
    left:100%;
    z-index:-1
}

.bp-coverpage-3 .bp-coverpage-content  .account-name {
    padding: 15px 0px 0px 0px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Manrope SemiBold !important;
}

.bp-coverpage-3 .account-name > span {
    width: 4.9in;
    display: inline-block;
    word-break: break-word;
}
.bp-coverpage-3 .bp-coverpage-content .report-date {
    padding: 10px 0px 15px 0px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Manrope SemiBold;
}


.bp-coverpage-3 hr {
    max-width: 52px;
    margin-left: 100px;
}

.bp-coverpage-3 > .bp-coverpage-footer {
    color: #5B5C64;
    font-family: Manrope SemiBold;       
}

.bp-coverpage-3 .bp-coverpage-footer > .footer-text {
   width: 93%;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    font-family: Manrope SemiBold;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en" class="" style="">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Print Portal</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Source+Sans+Pro&amp;display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Manrope&amp;display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
      @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Manrope&display=swap);

    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div>
      <div id="Report_1_Page_1"  class="page landscape" style="height:8.2in !important; width:11in !important;">
        <div class="bp-coverpage-3">
            <div class="bp-coverpage-header">
              <div class="header-section-top">                
              </div> 
              <span class="client-tag-line"> <img class="LogoImageSize" src="https://static4.depositphotos.com/1020822/359/v/950/depositphotos_3595189-stock-illustration-abstract-security-logo.jpg" alt="Logo"> </span>
              
              <div class="header-section-bottom"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="bp-coverpage-content">
            <div class= "content-section-top">
            <div class="report-name-container">
                <span class="report-name">Quarterly Review - United States -2022-1</span>
              </div>
            </div>            
            <div class= "content-section-bottom">
   <div class="bottom-shape">
    <div class="account-name">
                            <!-- <span>Niranja Industries Pension Fund - Region India</span>-->
                <span>Niranja Industries Pension Fund - Country India TEST 60 CHAR THEN MOVE TO NEXT LINE</span>
                </div>
              <div class="report-date">September 30, 2022</div> 
   </div>         
            </div>
            </div>            
            <div class="bp-coverpage-footer">
              <span class="footer-text">Please compare this report to your custodian’s account statement.</span>
            </div>
          
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

How can I manage the bottom box and the image alignment similar to the above layout? Below is the jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/niranjankala/4Lyg9hn5/14/

Comment: I would use a clip to get consistent and simpler code instead of the transparent border https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_clip.php

Comment: What is it to look like on narrow/protrait/different viewport aspect ratios? In particular, is the angle to remain the same? This will determine whether you can use clip-path or whether a different method is needed.

Comment: It is portrait view with fixed width and height. Due to older version of chromium engine, I am stick with the before and after Pseudo-classes. How can I specify the border width similar to polygon(50% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);

Answer (score 0):

Please check below example snippet:

```css
.page {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #DEDEDE;
}

.landscape {
    height: 8.2in;
    font-size: 10px;
    position: relative;
    page-break-after: always;
    /* page-break-inside: avoid; */
    font-family: Verdana;
}


.bp-coverpage-3 {   

    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}


.bp-coverpage-3  .bp-coverpage-header {
        width: 100%;
        height: 3.2in;
    }

.bp-coverpage-3 .LogoImageSize {
    max-height: 1.6in;
    max-width: 3.1in;
}

.bp-coverpage-3 .bp-coverpage-header > .header-section-top {
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 5%;
}

.bp-coverpage-3 .bp-coverpage-header .client-tag-line {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 25px;
}

.bp-coverpage-3 .bp-coverpage-header .header-section-bottom {
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 10%;
}

.bp-coverpage-3 .bp-coverpage-content {
    width: 100%;
    border:1px solid #999;
    font-family: Manrope SemiBold !important;
    background: url(https://as2.ftcdn.net/v2/jpg/04/38/64/95/1000_F_438649569_DsSHTkasH6GqqQXwu7FbRG0OMHstAc2D.jpg) no-repeat bottom -120px right -170px ;
    background-size: 80%;
}

.bp-coverpage-3  .content-section-top {
  background:transparent;
}

.bp-coverpage-3  .content-section-bottom {
  background-color:transparent;
}
.bp-coverpage-3 .bp-coverpage-content  .report-name-container {
        padding: 0px 0px 0px 40px;
        background: #61626B;
        width:35%;
        position:relative;
        z-index:1;
    }
.bp-coverpage-3 .bp-coverpage-content .report-name-container:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    top: 0;
    left: calc(100% - 58px);
    background: #61626b;
    clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
    width: 135px;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
}
.bp-coverpage-3 .bp-coverpage-content  .report-name-container:before {
  content:'';
  border-top: 90px solid #61626B;
  border-left: 120px solid transparent;
  border-right: 120px solid transparent;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  right:-80px;
        z-index:-1;
}
.bp-coverpage-3 .report-name-container > .report-name {
    font-size: 32px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    font-family: 'Manrope SemiBold';    
    word-break: break-word;
    width:2.8in;
    height:1.5in;    
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

.bp-coverpage-3 .bp-coverpage-content  .content-section-bottom .bottom-shape {
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 40px;
    background: #61626B;
    width:calc(40% + 25px);
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
    background:#E7E7E7;
}

.bp-coverpage-3 .bp-coverpage-content .content-section-bottom .bottom-shape:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: calc(100% - 67px);
    background: #e7e7e7;
    clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
    width: 135px;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
}


.bp-coverpage-3 .bp-coverpage-content  .account-name {
    padding: 15px 0px 0px 0px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Manrope SemiBold !important;
}

.bp-coverpage-3 .account-name > span {
    width: 4.9in;
    display: inline-block;
    word-break: break-word;
}
.bp-coverpage-3 .bp-coverpage-content .report-date {
    padding: 10px 0px 15px 0px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Manrope SemiBold;
}


.bp-coverpage-3 hr {
    max-width: 52px;
    margin-left: 100px;
}

.bp-coverpage-3 > .bp-coverpage-footer {
    color: #5B5C64;
    font-family: Manrope SemiBold;       
}

.bp-coverpage-3 .bp-coverpage-footer > .footer-text {
   width: 93%;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    font-family: Manrope SemiBold;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en" class="" style="">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Print Portal</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Source+Sans+Pro&amp;display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Manrope&amp;display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
      @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Manrope&display=swap);

    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div>
      <div id="Report_1_Page_1"  class="page landscape" style="height:8.2in !important; width:11in !important;">
        <div class="bp-coverpage-3">
            <div class="bp-coverpage-header">
              <div class="header-section-top">                
              </div> 
              <span class="client-tag-line"> <img class="LogoImageSize" src="https://static4.depositphotos.com/1020822/359/v/950/depositphotos_3595189-stock-illustration-abstract-security-logo.jpg" alt="Logo"> </span>
              
              <div class="header-section-bottom"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="bp-coverpage-content">
            <div class= "content-section-top">
            <div class="report-name-container">
                <span class="report-name">Quarterly Review - United States -2022-1</span>
              </div>
            </div>            
            <div class= "content-section-bottom">
   <div class="bottom-shape">
    <div class="account-name">
                            <!-- <span>Niranja Industries Pension Fund - Region India</span>-->
                <span>Niranja Industries Pension Fund - Country India TEST 60 CHAR THEN MOVE TO NEXT LINE</span>
                </div>
              <div class="report-date">September 30, 2022</div> 
   </div>         
            </div>
            </div>            
            <div class="bp-coverpage-footer">
              <span class="footer-text">Please compare this report to your custodian’s account statement.</span>
            </div>
          
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Here, I have used **clip-path** property.
Please let me know if you find any issues.

Comment: It working with the height of the div but these clip path is not similar to angle of lines. Do you have any idea to set the image positioning similar to desired layout.

Comment: You can use the first element from the CSS 50% and you can decrease it as per your angle: polygon(50% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);

Comment: Please try it once. Thanks

Comment: Looks good. Any suggestion for the image positioning

Comment: You can use background-position property

Comment: I have to export this content to the PDF so the older version of the chromium engine does not support this clip and clip-path.